# .NET EntityFramework FirstOrDefaultAync throwing cast error

Tags: .net, entity-framework, sqlite, asynchronous

I've got an issue where using `FirstOrDefaultAsync` throws an `InvalidCastException` when attempting to get a row from my database.  If I switch to `FirstOrDefault` without async then it loads the data fine.

**Works**

```
public async Task<Application> GetApplication(int id)
{
    return _context.Applications.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == id);
}
```

**Doesn't Work**

```
public async Task<Application> GetApplication(int id)
{
    return await _context.Applications.FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Id == id);
}
```

The schema for the `application` table looks like so:

```
CREATE TABLE `application` (
  `id`  INTEGER NOT NULL,
  `name`    TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  `application_id`  TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  `secret_key`  TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

The data in the database is:

```
+----+---------+----------------+------------+
| id |  name   | application_id | secret_key |
+----+---------+----------------+------------+
|  1 | TestApp | app123         | secret123  |
+----+---------+----------------+------------+
```

The first few lines of the stack trace are as follows:

```
at System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.GetFieldValue[T](Int32 ordinal)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.GetFieldValueAsync[T](Int32 ordinal, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
```

As `id` is the only Int32 field in the table, I'm guessing EF is struggling with this property, however I can't work out why it works when using `FirstOrDefault`.  Any ideas?

I'm using Entity Framework 6 with .NET 4.5.1.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use `FindAsync(id)`. This extension method is basically designed to work with `primary key`

Answer (score 1):

Can you update your question, as what you say works, really should not - FirstOrDefault() does not return Task, so you would get a cast exception there.

What you need is

```
public async Task<Application> GetApplicationAsync(int id)
{
    return await _context.Applications.FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Id == id);
}
```

Comment: That's what I have in my question under "Doesn't Work" :)  I'm aware that normally you wouldn't return `Task<Application>` for a non-async method, however it's still returning the entity fine.

Comment: I should also note that I don't have both implementations declared at the same time, I'm just changing the body.  There aren't two `Task<Application> GetApplication(int id)` methods.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using async method so you need to use

```
 public async Task<Application> GetApplication(int id)
{
    return await _context.Applications.FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Id == id);
}
```

But actually your Id column is primary key so you can use another linq extension method for your task like

```
public async Task<Application> GetApplication(int id)
{
    return await  _context.Applications.FindAsync(id);
}
```

`FindAsync(id)` is basically designed for `primary key` based selection. So It's recommended to use `FindAsync()`. Add

> Namespace:   System.ServiceModel.Discovery
>       Assembly:  System.ServiceModel.Discovery (in System.ServiceModel.Discovery.dll)

Actually you are using and I think Sqlite isn't thread-safe, so you shouldn't even want it to handle async requests. There is a library that sort-of makes Sqlite async, but I don't know if it works well. but try [github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL](http://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL)

Comment: What namespace is `FindAsync` under?  I've got `Find` but not `FindAsync`.  Looking at the MSDN docs it should be there for EF6, so that's a little confusing!

Comment: If it does not work you need to `Compile against .NET 4.5.1 rather than 4.5 and you will generally get better exception traces with async.`

Comment: Actually just realised it's missing because I'm using `IDbSet<T>` and not `DbSet<T>` - switched to `DbSet<T>` and now I have the `FindAsync` method.  However, using `FindAsync` hasn't resolved the issue - still receiving the `InvalidCastException` :(

Comment: Put try..catch() and update question with exact exception.

Comment: `Find()`  If an entity with the given primary key values exists in the context, then it is returned immediately without making a request to the store. Otherwise, a request is made to the store

Comment: are you sure you are getting the exception in `_context.Applications.FindAsync(id)` or after this line any unknown things creating exception?

Comment: Yeah it's definitely happening on that line.  Same happens when using `ToListAsync()`, or any other `xxxAsync` method.  I _am_ using SQLite so that may have something to do with it.

Comment: I think Sqlite isn't thread-safe, so you shouldn't even want it to handle async requests. There is a library that sort-of makes Sqlite async, but I don't know if it works well. but try https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL

Comment: @MANISHKUMARCHOUDHARY I think that's probably it.  No big deal, the app won't be getting much traffic so it's not really important for it to be async.  Thanks for your help!